# How to create an overlay menu from a button in Bootstrap (mobile only)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was told to create a separate mobile header for our website, which looks nothing like the desktop version. Therefore I decided to create a separate file for the HTML just for mobile. I don't need this to be responsive across different sizes as it will only be visible on xs devices. I am not using Bootstrap Navbar either so I just added my own hamburger menu button that will always be visible (on xs devices). Here's the header.

[image]

I want that when the user clicks the menu icon, a menu should overlay the current page. I found slide-in lateral menus that I didn't like because they pushed the page to the right. I want something to overlay but keep page below as is. The menu on the desktop site looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to keep the look pretty similar, very much like the Bootstrap styling for dropdowns.

What is the best way to go about doing this? 
Here's a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/MWYq5hVtZ0